# Circle with direction pointer in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, coordinates, markers

I am new to Leaflet and I am using leaflet 1.7.1.
My need is to put some custom markers on map.

I am currently using circles (as in: `L.circle([lat, lon], {radius: rad}).addTo(map);`) as markers (note radius *is* significant and should be in meters).

Problem is I need to add a "direction" to this circle essentially displaying something like:

[image: 45° circle]

I *think* I need to implement somethinh like `L.directedCircle([lat, lon], {radius: rad, heading=45}).addTo(map);`, but I'm unsure how to do that.

I also tried looking for plugins, but nothing seems to do what I need.

Note that the image above is just an example, I'm open to other options but that seems very simple (it's just a 4-points SVG poliline) and effective. If I can get georeferenced vertices I think I should be able to draw a polygon.

This essentially means to be able, given a point with `LatLon` coordinates, be able to get another point "10 meters with heading XX° from N" (and then another 10m (XX+180-5)°, 9m (XX+180)° and 10m (XX+180+5)°).

I'm using leaflet through pyqtlet2, but I'm prepared to "get my hands dirty" using directly JavaScript.

Comment: See `turf.destination` method in [turf.js](https://turfjs.org/) library.

Comment: Or `geographiclib`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44740076/generate-coordinates-given-distance-angle-from-a-center/44740317#44740317

Comment: Thanks @TomazicM, but I would prefer a Leaflet-only solution, if possible, as I need it essentially to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69772601/custom-drawing-rotated-svg-to-leaflet-map) and thus pulling in a whole new package seems excessive (and I do not really need very high precision (distances are of the order of meters so almost any reasonable approximation would be enough).

Comment: Thanks @IvanSanchez, Please see the comment above. What I really need is to [draw a custom oriented and sized marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69772601/custom-drawing-rotated-svg-to-leaflet-map). I thought about using a georeferenced polyLine, but any hint would be very welcome, either here or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69772601/custom-drawing-rotated-svg-to-leaflet-map)

Comment: Then please edit your question end describe what you really need, not how you decided to implement it.

Comment: @TomazicM I hope my needs are clearer now. Please ask if something is still missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution would be easy if your marker would be static one, like `L.circleMarker`. Since radius of your circle is in meters, there seems to be no ready available solution.

Given formulas from this page http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html, it's not hard to get destination point from origin point, bearing and distance.

Here is JS function to get coordinates of destination point:

```
Math.toRadians = function(degrees) {
  return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
}

Math.toDegrees = function(radians) {
  return radians * 180 / Math.PI;
}

function destinationPoint(origin, distance, bearing) {
  const radius = 6371e3;
  const Ad = distance / radius;
  const br = Math.toRadians(bearing);

  const lat1 = Math.toRadians(origin[0]), lon1 = Math.toRadians(origin[1]);

  const sinlat2 = Math.sin(lat1) * Math.cos(Ad) + Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(Ad) * Math.cos(br);
  const lat2 = Math.asin(sinlat2);
  const y = Math.sin(br) * Math.sin(Ad) * Math.cos(lat1);
  const x = Math.cos(Ad) - Math.sin(lat1) * sinlat2;
  const lon2 = lon1 + Math.atan2(y, x);

  const lat = Math.toDegrees(lat2);
  const lon = Math.toDegrees(lon2);

  return [lat, lon];
}
```

Simple test script:

```
var origin = [22.4757, 88.2111];
var distance = 10000;
var bearing = 45;

L.circle(origin, {radius: distance}).addTo(map);

var p1 = destinationPoint(origin, distance, bearing);
var p2 = destinationPoint(origin, distance, bearing + 183);
var p3 = destinationPoint(origin, distance, bearing + 177);
L.polygon([p1, p2, p3, p1]).addTo(map);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it solves my problem although I implemented the same logic in Python because I don't really grok JS (yet). A side question: AFAIK your code produces two separate layers so, if/when I need to delete this "marker" I will have to remember and remove them separately; is there any way to "group" them together?

Comment: Just put them together in a group layer.